# Ruby on rails - adding multiple choice checkboxes - ERROR - undefined method `check_box_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

I'm tying do add a new kind of answers to my polls app. It will be a multiple choice with checkboxes. The user can choose one or more possible answers from the checkboxes presented.
I'm struggling to make it work, I'm getting the error:

```
NoMethodError in Replies#new

undefined method `check_box_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fae8bd82f48>
```

right i have this models:

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reply
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :possible_answer
end
```

**poll.rb**

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title

  has_many :questions
  has_many :replies
end
```

**possible_answer.rb**

```
class PossibleAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll

  has_many :possible_answers
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :possible_answers, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['title'].blank? }
end
```

**reply.rb**

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

In the views I have a reply/new.html.erb that already work for radio and open answer questions, by rendering the partial by kind:

```
<h1><%= @poll.title %></h1>

<%= form_for [ @poll, @reply ] do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :answers do |c| %>
        <%= render c.object.question.kind, c: c %>
    <% end %>
    <p>
      <%=f.submit 'Finish poll', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

and the partial for the checkbox:

```
<p>                                                                             
  <%= c.label :value, c.object.question.title %>                                
</p>                                                                            
<div class="checkbox">                                                          
  <% c.object.question.possible_answers.each do |possible_answer| %>            
      <p>                                                                       
        <label>                                                                 
          <%= c.check_box_tag :possible_answer_id, possible_answer.id %>        
          <%= possible_answer.title %>                                          
          <%= c.hidden_field :question_id %>                                    
        </label>                                                                
      </p>                                                                      
  <% end %>                                                                     
</div>
```

**replies_controller.rb**

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @poll = Poll.find params[:poll_id]
    @reply = @poll.replies.build
    @poll.questions.each { |question| @reply.answers.build question: question }
  end

  def create
    @poll = Poll.find params[:poll_id]
    @reply = @poll.replies.build reply_params

    if @reply.save
      redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Thank you for the taking the poll.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private
    def reply_params
      params.require(:reply).permit(:poll_id, {
          answers_attributes: [:value, :question_id, :reply_id, :possible_answer_id] })
    end
end
```

**questions_controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_poll
  before_action :set_kind_questions


  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    #@question = Question.new
    @question = @poll.questions.build
    5.times { @question.possible_answers.build }
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    #@question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question = @poll.questions.build(question_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @question.update(question_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @question }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :kind, :poll_id, { possible_answers_attributes: [:title, :question_id] })
    end

    def set_kind_questions
      @kind_options = [
          ['Open Answer','open'],
          ['Multiple Radio Choice', 'radio'],
          ['Multiple Checkbox Choice','checkbox']
      ]
    end

    def set_poll
      @poll = Poll.find params[:poll_id]
    end
end
```

**Answers migration table**

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.references :reply, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :question, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :possible_answer, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :value

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Probably I have to use has_and_belongs_to_many association in the answers model but I'm not getting how. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try to just use check_box_tag as below:

```
<%= check_box_tag( 'possible_answer_ids['+ possible_answer.id.to_s+']', possible_answer.id) %>
```

Comment: it worked!!!thanks alot! but now when i submit the poll i have another error in the polls/show.html.erb, i'm getting: undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass in the line that contains <%= answer.value.present? ? answer.value : answer.possible_answer.title %>. that's because now i have more than one answer for one question, right?

Comment: Is it the `1-N` relationship?

Comment: the answer belongs to a possible_answer, so it's not one to many

Comment: That happens probably because the `answer` doesn't have a `possible_answer` relationship.

Comment: there's a relationship between them but probably not the right one

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reply
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :possible_answer
end

Comment: You have set the relationship between the two `Class` but probably not for that `instance`. To check it, replace `<%= answer.value.present? ? answer.value : answer.possible_answer.title %>` with `<%= answer.value.present? ? answer.value : (answer.possible_answer.nil? ? 'No possible answer' : answer.possible_answer.title) %>`

Comment: there's no error now, but the answers are not being saved in the anwsers table, i'm choosing more than one choice but it's always showing "No possible answer"

Comment: Please put your `controller` here

Comment: It is unreadable for the code in comment. Please update it in your question.

Comment: No way to do it in comment. Just update in your question please.

Comment: sorry, noob here... :) just edited the question with the replies controller and the questions controller

Comment: You are expecting parameter `possible_answer_id` while I gave `possible_answer_ids` in my answer. Just change anyone of them to make it consist.

Comment: changed to `possible_answer_id` but still won't save to answers table. i updated my question with migration for the Answers table.

Comment: still can't make it work, it won't save to the answers table. tried the radio buttons and the open answer and they save the answer to answers table...can't figure it out...